# Leaving spaces every 4 numbers

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular8

Using ionic 4 and Angular 8 , i am trying to leave a space every 4 digits the user inputs but it breaks suddenly, what i think it does is every action i do as a user after 4 numbers it leaves a space.

this is my function:

```
maskInput(input){

    let masked:
    Array<String> = input.replace(" ", "").split("");

    let res = "";

    for(let i = 0; i< masked.length; i++) {
    if(i % 4) res += masked[i]

      else res += " " + masked[i]

    }
    return res
  }
```

calling this back through **(ngModelChange)** in **ion-input**,
am i doing something wrong here? could it be the for loop?

fixed the spaces problem by changing the code to:

```
Array<String> = input.replace(" ", "").split(" ").join("").split("");
```

but still it counts spaces as Input.

Comment: Could you please share template code?

Comment: i fixed it by using Array<String> = input.replace(" ", "").split(" ").join("").split("");
but it still have a problem where it counts the spaces as part of the input and doesn't allow the user to put the full card number.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what your question is, if you need a function that add spaces every 4 digits, here's one :

```js
const input = "765389764";

function addSpaceEvery4Digit(input) {
  let newInput = "";
  for (let i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
    newInput += input.charAt(i);
    if ((i % 4 === 0) && i < input.length - 1) {
      newInput += " ";
    }
  }
  return newInput;
}

const res = addSpaceEvery4Digit(input);
console.log(res);
```

## EDIT :

You should iterate on the string itself, not an array of string, in your code :

change : `let masked:Array<String> = input.replace(" ", "").split("");`

with : `let masked:string = input.replace(" ", "");`

Answer (score -1):

the problem was with the split only, i changed my function to this and it worked:
(split, join, split)

```
maskInput(input) {

    const masked:
    // tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types
    Array<String> = input.replace(' ', '').split(' ').join('').split('');

    let res = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < masked.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && (i) % 4) { res += masked[i]; }

      // tslint:disable-next-line: one-line
      else { res += ' ' + masked[i]; }

    }
    console.log(input);
    return res;
  }
```